# Evolution Calendar Sync with UbuntuOne?

Tags: ubuntu-one, evolution, sync, cloud

I'm assuming this is a feature what will be added in the future for mobile paying customers? 
I know this feature would be very appealing to users wanting to move away from Windows/Outlook and start using Ubuntu/Evolution...

Keep up the great work!!

Answer (score 1):

I have my evolution calendar on ubuntu one. I just go into .local file find my way to the evolution folder and the calendar and right click and sync it with ubuntu one. works great between my netbook and desktop, ensures when i change one calendar the other does, making I have just one calendar. I am not sure if this will help with you and a mobile tho? Sorry if my answer is not more detailed about finding the file, I am at work stuck on XP, so going off memory here.

Dustin

Comment: I tried it and keep getting "U1 Conflict." Maybe Ubuntu One has changed since this was written.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Calendar Sync at the moment is not implemented.

If you are interested at this feauture see this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/448105

Answer (score 0):

I create a ticket on Ubuntu One Server to get this feature.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/924870

Hope to see it soon.

regards,
BlueCase